# Align items in a RecyclerView at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` inside of a `ConstraintLayout` whose top starts at the bottom of a `textView`, and whose bottom stretches down to the parent.  I want the items in this `RecyclerView` to default to the bottom of the `RecyclerView`.  I tried adding `gravity="bottom"` and also tried the same thing with `foregroundGravity` and `layout_gravity`. I also tried adding `layout_gravity="bottom"` to my `recyclerView` item's layout.  Still, all the items in the `recyclerView` continues to default to the top.  Is there anything i can do to make sure the items are at the bottom?  Here is the xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="needed to unlock next coupon"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/irrelevant_tv"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xl"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_tv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't want to do `wrap_content` on `recyclerView` either, because otherwise it is not `scrollable` (I always have 3 items in this `recyclerView`, and based on the user's display settings, the `recyclerView` can get pushed off the screen, which requires me to be able to scroll)

Comment: Use LinearLayout for better control

Comment: Can you paste all your xml code here. so i can give you refined code.

Comment: If i use a linear layout then i will not be able to stretch the recycler view to the bottom, which is what i want to do in order to make it scrollable.  Otherwise i have to do wrap_content

Comment: Can i see your required layout then, any screen?

Comment: adjusted my layout so i don't need a scroll anymore. i'm good

Comment: Cool by the way i have also implemented constraint layout many times. and yes it creates issues to have scrollview recyclerview and contraint layout combine.

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or ⌘+K to properly format your source code chunks.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the method `LinearLayoutManager#setStackFromEnd(boolean)`.
Then your items will be rendered starting from bottom of view.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)).

Comment: This is the right answer. Why didnt @hermt2 accept it?

Answer (score 5):

You can also add this to XML layout:

```
app:stackFromEnd="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this for the RecyclerView in XML Layout:

```
app:flow_verticalAlign="bottom"
```